# How do you create an Editable Region?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, web-part, css

How do you create an editable region in SharePoint Designer 2010?

You can only fully edit the website in SharePoint Designer 2010 through advanced mode. If the region does not have any editable regions then you cannot edit in normal mode.

I just want to know how you add an editble region. Does adding a webpart do this for me?

Also one more question can you add CSS to this? Rather than it being clumped togehtor with the XML/HTML code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different Web Parts for different purposes, for example Content Editor Web Part under Media and Content category will allow you to put CSS and HTML, it also has Edit HTML option so you can define your CSS, HTML, JS etc.

But that is useful when you are using Web Part pages.. If you want the content authors for your website use some specific fields to define the content of a page, you might need to think of Page Layouts.. (you might need to turn on Publishing Feature for the site collection and site)

The key for using Page Layouts is that you create a Content Type with defined site columns, define Parent Content Type to Page/Article Page.. (have one of the Publishing HTML field) and you can create a Page Layout based on this content type.. Than you can create pages based on the page layout..

References

[Using the Content Editor Web Part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/using-the-content-editor-web-part-HA101794745.aspx)

[Page Layouts in SharePoint 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/04/02/page-layouts-in-sharepoint.aspx)